# got error when json parsing message (in german lang.)

Tags: php, jquery, json

I did implement submission using ajaxsubmit. My php code (action function),

```
$printArr['succ'] = '1';
$printArr['msg'] = 'Ihr Passwort wurde erfolgreich geändert';
echo json_encode($printArr);
exit;
```

When I get response in js function it gives me error. my js code,

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
            var options = {
                url:$('#persdata2').attr('action'),
                success:function(response){
                    data = $.parseJSON(response);
                    $('#password_err_content').html(data.msg);
                    $('#password_err_blk').slideDown();
                }
            };
            $("form#persdata2").ajaxSubmit(options);
            return false;
        }
```

**Error**:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object
```

If I pass simple message in like

`$printArr['msg'] = 'Password change successfully';`

then everything is fine.

Help me out!

Answer (score 1):

May be you would like to try `json_encode($printArr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`

[CodeViper Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VcJANw).

[JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-unescaped-unicode): 
*Encode multibyte Unicode characters literally (default is to escape as \uXXXX). Available since PHP 5.4.0.*

Comment: lower version (older than PHP 5.4.0.)

Comment: Than seems you need to encode your string first `$printArr['msg'] = json_encode('Ihr Passwort wurde erfolgreich geändert');`

Answer (score 0):

Please try by removing the \ after slideDown(); \

```
   submitHandler: function(form) {
        var options = {
            url:$('#persdata2').attr('action'),
            success:function(response){
                data = $.parseJSON(response);
                $('#password_err_content').html(data.msg);
                $('#password_err_blk').slideDown(); // here the / is given 
            }
        };
        $("form#persdata2").ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    }
```

hope it will help!